# Question about invisible tab bar when presenting viewcontroller in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

I will press the red login button at the bottom of the picture and try to log in.
login button => "로그인"

After that, log in.

```
let moreVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MoreViewController") as! MoreViewController

                moreVC.definesPresentationContext = true
                moreVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
                let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: moreVC)

                self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

If the login proceeds without error, the above code will be called to display the screen when the login is completed.

If the flow proceeds as the code above, this screen appears.

[image]

The screen shown is not fullscreen, and the tabbar at the bottom is gone. The screen I want is the screen below.

[image]

How can I present a tab bar when presenting the screen?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are embedding the `moreVC` in a navigation controller and then presenting that, the navigation controller’s `modalPresentationStyle` needs to be set to `.fullScreen`